# Disable selection on first column of grid

Tags: grid, selection, cell, extjs4.1

Is there a way to disable selection on the first column of a grid only. I have 2nd and 3rd column as 'checkcolumn', which fires selection for that row. That's why I cannot entirely use

```
disableSelection: true
```

on the grid, because this would disable the selection fire event on checkboxes. The first column is just a text, and I don't want selection of that row when the first column's row is clicked.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeitemmousedown` event will probably work for you, add it as a listener where you declare your grid and return false when the event's target is the first cell in the row:

```
listeners: {
    beforeitemmousedown: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts)
    {
        if(item.cells[0] == e.target.parentElement)
            return false;
    }
}
```